# How to run bokeh app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bokeh

I'm trying to figure out how could I combine bokeh and heroku. 
When I run the code below locally, I get the following output:

[image]
However, in hereku, I got an empty browser page. So I couldnt know wha=ere is my mistake. Could you help me with that ?  Here is the code I use:

**mytest.py**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.driving import cosine
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

x = np.linspace(0, 4*pi, 80)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure()
r1 = p.line([0, 4*pi], [-1, 1], color="firebrick")
r2 = p.line(x, y, color="navy", line_width=4)

# open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())

@cosine(w=0.03)
def update(step):
    # updating a single column of the the *same length* is OK
    r2.data_source.data["y"] = y * step
    r2.glyph.line_alpha = 1 - 0.8 * abs(step)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)

session.show(p) # open the document in a browser

session.loop_until_closed() # run forever
```

**requirements.txt**

```
appdirs==1.4.3
backports-abc==0.5
bokeh==0.12.4
certifi==2017.1.23
futures==3.0.5
Jinja2==2.9.5
MarkupSafe==1.0
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.13.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
tornado==4.4.2
```

**Proctofile**

```
web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --host=protected-sands-65334.herokuapp.com --host=* --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders mytest.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work by removing the lines in the code describing session, and adding the following:

```
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Also, take care that the name of the file containing the command to run the bokeh server should be **Procfile**, and nothing else (you typed **Proctofile**).

Comment: add some more info